# button not working on simple html clicker game

Tags: javascript, html, button

I started to try making a simple clicker game but I got stuck on getting the button to work. I have tried for hours please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
var number = 0;
var numberPerClick = 1;
</script>
<html>
<body>
<h1>number clicker</h1>
<p id="numbers"></p>
<button><a herf="#" onClick="click()">click</a></button>
<script>
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = number;
function click() {
number += numberPerClick;
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = number;
}
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was just messing around with it in fiddle and got this to work. http://jsfiddle.net/rBpVD/8783/. Replace click() with myFunction(). Not too sure why, but it's possible there is conflict with another click function.

```
<body>
  <h1>number clicker</h1>
  <p id="numbers"></p>
  <button onClick="myFunction()">click</button>
  <script>
  var number = 0;
  var numberPerClick = 1;
  document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = number;
  function myFunction() {
    number += numberPerClick;
    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = number;
  }
  </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: You're correct that it's conflicting with javascript's click() function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_click

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `<button>` element is swallowing the click event so that the `<a>` element never gets the click. Try moving the `onclick` to the `<button>` element and replacing the `<a>` tag with some static text.